# Can't find uninstaller in Folx downloader.mac.dmg

Tags: safari, macos

I'm new to OS X and I don't know too much about it.  After installing Folx on my Mac I realized I didn't like it.  I tried to remove it but the plugin didn't remove.  When I download any file with Safari it gives an error for the Folx plugin. I've searched and found [this](http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/downloader-macos/uninstall.html) website that shows how to uninstall Folx.  I can't find the uninstaller file in downloader.mac.dmg.

How can I remove Folx completely?

Comment: The Flox Uninstallation you've linked is for version 2 of Flox while the current version is 5. Which version are you using?  [Directions](http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/uninstall-mac.html) for the latest version: "_Uninstall Apps on Mac Open the Applications folder in Finder, select the app and drag it to Trash (located at the end of Dock). Then choose Finder → Empty Trash. When you empty the trash, the app is permanently removed from your Mac._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X is a bit different. After putting the application itself in the trash, you should probably use safari preferences to remove the extension. Once you do that you do that, you might want to log out and back in.  Then empty the trash.

Alternatively you can look in the library folders - use finder go menu and choose "Go to Folder" and look in both below locations:

```
~/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins
```

Note the space is encoded with a \ but you can skip that most of the time if you are not pasting into terminal or scripting. Delete any plugins to be nuked and reboot if you removed any from the second system library folder. Then empty trash.